# Using encapsulated collections with inheritance in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core 2.0 and would like to encapsulate collections to be able to run business logic when adding to the collection. (see https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2016/10/28/collection-navigation-properties-and-fields-in-ef-core-1-1/)

This works great *when the protected field and public getter is of the same type*, but I am unable to make this work with an inheritance scheme.

My code looks roughly like this:

```
public abstract class ItemBase
{
    protected readonly List<DetailBase> _details = new List<DetailBase>();

    protected void AddDetail(DetailBase detail)
    {
        _details.Add(detail);

        // shared business logic
    }
}

public abstract class DetailBase
{
    // ...
}

public class DetailA : DetailBase
{
    // ...
}

public class DetailB : DetailBase
{
    // ...
}

public class ItemA : ItemBase
{
    public IEnumerable<DetailA> Details => _details.Cast<DetailA>();
    public void AddDetail(DetailA detail)
    {
        base.AddDetail(detail);

        // specific business logic for A
    }
}

public class ItemB : ItemBase
{
    public IEnumerable<DetailB> Details => _details.Cast<DetailB>();
    public void AddDetail(DetailB detail)
    {
        base.AddDetail(detail);

        // specific business logic for B
    }
}
```

But this will raise the following exception:

```
InvalidOperationException: The type of navigation property 'Details' on the entity type 'ItemA' is '<CastIterator>d__34<DetailA>' which does not implement ICollection<DetailA>. Collection navigation properties must implement ICollection<> of the target type.
```

How do I properly cast the collection in my derived classes so that it is accessible using the public getter **Details**?

For now I have solved it by duplicating the protected field in my derived classes, but this does not feel as clean as the code above.

```
public class ItemA : ItemBase
{
    protected readonly List<DetailA> _details = new List<DetailA>();
    public IEnumerable<DetailA> Details => _details;
    public void AddDetail(DetailA detail)
    {
        base.DoSharedLogicOnAdd(detail);

        // specific business logic for A
    }
}
```

Comment: In your derived class try this `public IEnumerable<DetailA> Details => _details.Cast<DetailA>().AsEnumerable();`

Comment: Thanks @Smit but Cast<DetailA> already returns an IEnumerable<DetailA>. Tried adding AsEnumerable() but it doesn't make any difference unfortunately.